# How to append new rows to "dbc.Table.from_dataframe" dash component when new JSON data is received?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dashboard

Here is a sample dashboard which publishes and subscribe to MQTT messages using `plotly dash`. Upon receiving the message from a particular topic in `JSON`, a dataframe is created and is populated to a `dbc.Table.from_dataframe` having `id = gw_table`. The requirement is when a new JSON data is received the data table needs to be appended with a **new row**, where as now in the below script it repopulates the 1st row with new received data.

Reading from the documentation and other similar question I tried with `dcc.store` but was not successful.

`app.py`

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import flask
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import json
import dash_mqtt
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True


TEST_SERVER = 'localhost'
TEST_SERVER_PORT = 1884
#TEST_SERVER_PATH = 'websockets'
MQTT_TOPIC_Registration = 'posttopic'

MQTT_TOPIC_Registration_Response = '#'

app.layout = html.Div([

                        
                        dcc.Tabs([
                           dcc.Tab(id = 'gw_id_tab', label='Registration', children = [
                                html.Div([ 
                                    dash_mqtt.DashMqtt(
                                                            id='mqtt',
                                                            broker_url=TEST_SERVER,
                                                            broker_port = TEST_SERVER_PORT,
                                                            #broker_path = TEST_SERVER_PATH,
                                                            topics=[MQTT_TOPIC_Registration, MQTT_TOPIC_Registration_Response]
                                                            ),
 
                           
                                        html.Div([
                                                    html.Button('Register', id='post-val', n_clicks=0)
                                                    
                                                ],style = {'marginTop': 50, 'margin-left' : '600px'}),
                                        
                                        html.Br(),
                                        
                                        html.Div(
                                            
                                            
                                            id= 'gw_table'
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            ),
                                        html.Div([
                                            dcc.ConfirmDialog(
                                                                id='confirm',
                                                                message='Are you sure you want to continue ?',
                                                            )]),
                          
                                                      

                          
                                ],style={'width':'100%', 'margin': 20})

                            ]),
                            
                            
                            dcc.Tab(label='TAB2', children = [
                                       html.Div([
                                            
                                              html.H3('Tab content 2')
                                            
                                            ])
                                
                                ])                            

    ]),
    html.Div(id='tabs-content')
    
])




@app.callback(
    Output('confirm', 'displayed'),
    [Input('post-val', 'n_clicks')]
    
    )


def display_confirm(clicked):
    
    if clicked:
        return True
    return False


   
@app.callback(
    Output('gw_table','children'),
    [Input('mqtt', 'incoming')]
    )

def update_table(incoming_message):
    if (incoming_message):
        
        gw_json =  incoming_message['payload']
        gw_table = pd.DataFrame([pd.read_json(gw_json,  typ='series')])
        return dbc.Table.from_dataframe(gw_table)
        
    else:
        return dash.no_update
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0',port=8050,debug=True)
```

So, How to append a new row to the `dbc.Table.from_dataframe` when new JSON data is received?

Answer (score 1):

By inspecting the Table object that is created using the `dbc.Table.from_dataframe`, we can see that its children attribute is loaded with the necessary rows and header elements from the dataframe. So if you already have a Table (eg. table_1) loaded from a dataframe, and you wish to add new JSON data then convert it to a dataframe (eg. df_2) and add it with table_1's data, so something like this:

```
df_2 = pd.read_json(new_json)
table_2 = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df_2)
table_3 = dbc.Table()
table_3.children = table_1.children+table_2.children[1:] # remove the first element from table_2's children as this contains its header and is not needed
table_1 = table_3 # to override table_1 with the new data
```

Of course, this code assumes that the new JSON is structured identically to that of the original data you wish to append to so be careful of this. If you wish to conserve other properties from table_1 like `style` or `className`, then just assign table_3's attribute to that of table_1's and you'll preserve that attribute in the new table.

Edit:
It's not clear if you intend to refresh the entire app to get this new JSON or you grab this without refreshing. I'll assume the latter for now, in which case you should use the `dcc.interval` component that will refresh your app without having to click refresh manually, and so you can now create a callback on this interval, grab the data from the original table and add the new JSON to it using the method I stated above.